# Java asyncHttpClient new thread for each connection

Tags: java, asynchttpclient

Im doing library in java, library is for calling external service API.
For this I am using [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client)

Some part of code:

```
 public CompletableFuture<Optional<TokensResponse>> clientCredentialsGrant(String clientId, String clientSecret, String deviceId, Optional<String> scope) {
        AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = asyncHttpClient();
        BoundRequestBuilder requestBuilder = asyncHttpClient
                .preparePost(host + "/oauth2/token")
                .addFormParam("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                .addFormParam("device_id", deviceId)
                .addFormParam("client_id", clientId)
                .addFormParam("client_secret", clientSecret);

        if (scope.isPresent()) {
            requestBuilder.addFormParam("scope", scope.get());
        }

        return runRequestWithTokenResponse(requestBuilder, asyncHttpClient);
    }
```

and if some project which is using this lib I will run for example 1000 requests even if they will finish I end up with a lot of threads hanged.
After reach request I am doing:

```
asyncHttpClient.close();
```

Can I define some thread pool to be used ?

> Typically, AHC will usually underperform if you create a new client
>   for each request, as it will create new threads and connection pools
>   for each

This is what I am actually doing..

Answer (score 3):

when you initialize the object AsyncHttpClient

you can do this , connection pool behaviour can be configured via AsyncHttpClientConfig:

```
AsyncHttpClient http = asyncHttpClient(config()
    .setMaxConnections(500)
    .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(200)
    .setPooledConnectionIdleTimeout(100)
    .setConnectionTtl(500)
);
```

Comment: can I easily use just one httpclient ? while it will be used by many concurrent calls ?

Comment: @Baku yes you can do it.

Comment: one more question, wont be a problem if this will live while app is running all the time without closing it ?

Comment: That is what the pool does, keep alive a few connection to rehused when you need. So you don't open a new connection each time. You need to check which is better for tou application.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define a thread pool. AHC takes care of concurrent execution.
Just create one AHC instance and use it everywhere.
For example, make this a class field:

`AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = asyncHttpClient();`

Under the hood AHC has two types of threads:

1. For I/O operation. 
   On your screen, it's AsyncHttpClient-x-x
   threads. AHC creates **2*core_number** of those.
2. For timeouts.
   On your screen, it's AsyncHttpClient-timer-1-1 thread. Should be
   only **one**.

Any different number means you’re creating multiple clients. It's redundant in your case.